# Problems with cordova: screen flashes, no PNG images are displayed

Tags: cordova, ios14, xcode12

I am trying to troubleshoot cordova problems with my application, but I can't solve it. Up to iOS 13.x the application worked perfectly. The following issues occur with the iOS 14.x update:

- the display emits white flashes intermittently (both when it should show an image and not)
- PNG images inserted and created by me are not displayed

According to my hypothesis there could be problems accessing the "content security" but I tried to update the info.plist file. I tried to insert in the config.xml:

```
 allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media 'true' 
 allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content 'true' 
 allows-local-networking 'true'
```

and also local: 8080 etc

The problem is still not solved. I tried to update to the latest version of Cordova 6.1.1 but the situation doesn't change. In addition, an absence of "resource" "LaunchStoryboard" is reported.

Below are two screenshots and a video of the problem:

[image: Error image in xcode]

[image: missing resource]

Link video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dw7yDsm_RCY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: did you get any solution for that?